# C++ vertically align declarations in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, alignment, clang-format

I try to do vertical declaration alignment in Visual Studio Code.

This code:

```
struct A {
  double a;
  int b;
}
```

must be converted into this:

```
struct A {
  double a;
  int    b;
}
```

Note, that here is not assignment, this is only declaration of struct with aligned fields.

Is there any extension for Visual Studio Code that does this?

Comment: Have you looked at `clang-format`?

Comment: Please only tag actual code as code, not words or names of things.

Comment: @DanM. I can't found option that does such alignment. Maybe I do not see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Clang-format

*Possibly*, you should also be able to use `clang-format` and its `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` option, but I haven't yet verified whther this is viable also for consecutive class member declarations (if not, this section will be removed):

> **`AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` (`bool`)**
>
> If `true`, aligns consecutive declarations.
>
> This will align the declaration names of consecutive lines. This will
>   result in formattings like
>
> ```
> int         aaaa = 12;
> float       b = 23;
> std::string ccc = 23;
> ```

### Visual Studio Code Formatter: Code alignment

The extension mentioned in the stricken parts below applies to Visual Studio; not Visual Studio Code (as was requested by OP). The same author has released an early adapted version of Code alignment for VSCode, however:

- [Visual Studio Code > Formatters > Code alignment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.codealignment-vscode)

> #### Current State
>
> Many of Code alignment's best features are currently missing. The plan
>   is to release early and release often, and to eventually reach parity.
>
> Main code alignment repository:
>   https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment
>
> ...

<s>The Visual Studio extension [Code alignment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment) allows you to format e.g. struct members in the way you show in your example.</s>

Citing [it's documentation](http://www.codealignment.com/Details.html):

> The Code alignment extension allows you to align by more than just the equals ...
>
> #### Some more examples
>
> ```
> private string m_firstName = string.Empty; => private string  m_firstName = string.Empty; 
> private string m_surname = string.Empty;   => private string  m_surname   = string.Empty; 
> private int m_age = 18;                    => private int     m_age       = 18; 
> private Address m_address;                 => private Address m_address;
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: The clang-format was spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

[clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) with "AlignConsecutiveDeclarations" outputs:

```
struct A {
  double a;
  int    b;
}
```

Comment: yes it is, thank you

Answer (score -1):

For those who use [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), there is an option in `Editor > Code Style > C/C++`. In the `Wrapping and Braces` tab, you can check the `Variable groups | Align in columns` checkbox.

[image]